# Confused about repositories in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine, repository, repository-pattern

I'm trying to implement Repositories in my app to separate DQL from the rest of the Entity logic but I am getting a Class `'UserRepository' not found in /home/fiodorovich/public_html/tests/library/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php on line 567` exception.

This is what my User class has:

```
/**
 * Description of User
 * @Table(name="users")
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository")
 * @author fiodorovich
 */
```

And this is the repository I've created:

```
namespace Federico\Entity\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getAllUsers () {
        $users = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM Federico\Entity\User u JOIN u.countries')->getResult();
        return $users;
    }

    public function getUser ($id) {
        $query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT u, c FROM Federico\Entity\User u JOIN u.countries c WHERE c.user = ?1');
        $query->setParameter(1, $id);
        $userModel = $query->getSingleResult();
        return $userModel;
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the line I use to call it from the controller:

```
 $this->em->getRepository('Federico\Entity\User')->getAllUsers();
```

Any help will be cool as I really want to use repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `@Entity(repositoryClass="Repository\UserRepository")` - relative to the Entity
because I assume your repository classes are in `Federico\Entity\Repository`

Comment: and how do you pass the entity manager to your repositories? I alwyas instantiate it like this `$this->em = Zend_Registry::get('em');` but this time it's not working and if I var_dump it I can see it's null

Answer (score 3):

IIRC unless both, repository and entity class are within the very same namespace you have to use fully qualified namespace name, ie: `@Entity(repositoryClass="Federico\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")`